# Python, print out keys of element sums of each possible combinations in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, combinations

Below lines are created to iterate and sum each possible element combinations in a dictionary. For example, if the length of dictionary is 5, I want the sum of any 2 elements, any 3 elements, any 4 elements.

```
import itertools

di = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 34, 'd': 24}

dict_len = range(len(di)-2, len(di))

for l in dict_len:
    d_values = list(itertools.combinations(di.values(), l))
    for d in d_values:
        print d
```

Output:

```
35
3
25
36
58
26
37
59
27
60
```

How can I have the keys of the values print out as well? like:

```
a + c = 35
a + b = 3
a + d = 25
b + c = 36
c + d = 58
b + d = 26
a + b + c =37
a + c + d =59
a + b + d =27
c + b + d =60
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output (as specified in the question):

```
import itertools

di = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 34, 'd': 24}

dict_len = range(len(di)-2, len(di))

for l in dict_len:
    d_values = list(itertools.combinations(di.values(), l))
    d_keys = list(itertools.combinations(di.keys(), l))
    for i in range(len(d_values)):
        print " + ".join(d_keys[i]), "=", sum(d_values[i])
```

Output:

```
a + c = 35
a + b = 3
a + d = 25
c + b = 36
c + d = 58
b + d = 26
a + c + b = 37
a + c + d = 59
a + b + d = 27
c + b + d = 60
```

Answer (score 1):

You could something like this:

```
di = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 34, 'd': 24}

dict_len = range(len(di)-2, len(di))

for l in dict_len:
    d_values = list(itertools.combinations(di.values(), l))
    d_keys =  list(itertools.combinations(di.keys(), l))
    for d,k in zip(d_values,d_keys):
        print(k,sum(d))
```

Which generates the output:

```
('a', 'b') 3
('a', 'c') 35
('a', 'd') 25
('b', 'c') 36
('b', 'd') 26
('c', 'd') 58
('a', 'b', 'c') 37
('a', 'b', 'd') 27
('a', 'c', 'd') 59
('b', 'c', 'd') 60
```

Comment: thank you. however another answer gives what exactly I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. You can do it like this:

```
import itertools

di = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 34, 'd': 24}

for n in range(2, len(di)):
  for pairs in itertools.combinations(di.items(), n):
      keys, values = zip(*pairs)  # Note 1
      print("{} = {}".format(' + '.join(keys), sum(values)))
```

which results in

```
a + b = 3
a + c = 35
a + d = 25
b + c = 36
b + d = 26
c + d = 58
a + b + c = 37
a + b + d = 27
a + c + d = 59
b + c + d = 60
```

---

Notes:

1. Notice the `zip(*iterable)` construction which changes the grouping order. For instance it takes you from `[('foo', 1), ('bar', 2)]` to `[('foo', 'bar'), (1, 2)]` thus effectively grouping the `keys` and `values` together.

Comment: thank you for the nice lines! hope you don't mind I chose the  answer which is easier to understand, especially for beginners. :)